# var is undefined if i declare it window.onload

Tags: javascript, html

I can't access to argsButtons var outside functions and i don't know why

HTML:

```
<div class="args-container" id="args">
    <button type="button" id="nuclear">click to see nuclear</button>
    <button type="button" id="geothermal">click to see geothermal</button>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
let argsButtons;

window.onload = function(){
    argsButtons = Array.from(document.getElementById("args").children);
}

//HERE IS THE ERROR (argsButtons is undefined)
argsButtons.forEach(e => e.addEventListener("click", myFunc()))
```

Comment: Why don't you place it inside your onload function? argButtons.foreach gets triggered before the window onload triggers.

Comment: `window.onload = ...` assigns a function to run, when that event happens. The rest of your code after that, proceeds immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get those button onload! you can simply do this:

```js
const argsContainer = document.querySelector('.args-container');
const argsButtons = argsContainer.querySelectorAll('button');

function myFunc() {
  console.log('clicked!')
}

argsButtons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', myFunc);
});
```